# Phonegap android finger slide (switch screens)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've just began using phonegap and its a great framework, but I was wondering if it is possible to detect when a finger slide occours and "change the screen" like a image slide show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are great frameworks like jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch that allow you to do that.

I suggest you take a look a all you can do with Sencha Touch. You should particularly take a look at User Interface > Carousel [on this link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/carousel)

Then if you're interested in working with Sencha Touch, [here's the API](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your framework, you can listen for a swipe event. For example, jQuery Mobile supports this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html